# Sorting a string

Tags: string, vba, excel, sorting

I'm trying to sort a string 'typestr' alphabetically:

```
typestr = "cda"
Dim temp As String
For i = 1 To Len(typeStr) - 1
    For j = i + 1 To Len(typeStr)
        If Mid(typeStr, i, 1) > Mid(typeStr, j, 1) Then
            temp = Mid(typeStr, i, 1)
            typeStr = Replace(typeStr, Mid(typeStr, i, 1), Mid(typeStr, j, 1), i, 1)
            typeStr = Replace(typeStr, Mid(typeStr, j, 1), temp, j, 1)
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

This all works fine until I come to the last Replace-function. Post first Replace-function the string is

```
typestr = ada
```

while my 'temp'-string is

```
temp = c
```

Since j = 3 at this point, the last replace should replace only the last a in ada, but what happens is that typestr gets replaced with  temp

```
typestr = c
```

Comment: A belated welcome to the site!  A reminder to check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [MCVE page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for tips on improving question quality. 
 Glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an easier *and much faster* way using `ArrayList`:

```
Function SortString(inputStr As String) As String
    Dim list As Object
    Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    For i = 1 To Len(inputStr)
        list.Add (Mid$(inputStr, i, 1))
    Next
    list.Sort

    SortString = Join(list.ToArray, "")
End Function
```

**Usage:**

```
MsgBox SortString("cbazyx")
```

**Output:**

> abcxyz

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Alphabetically_SortArray()

my_string = InputBox("Provide a string. It will be sorted alphabetically")

Dim buff() As String
ReDim buff(Len(my_string) - 1)
For i = 1 To Len(my_string)
    buff(i - 1) = Mid$(my_string, i, 1)
Next

Dim myArray As Variant
Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim TempTxt1 As String
Dim TempTxt2 As String

myArray = buff

'Alphabetize Sheet Names in Array List
  For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    For y = x To UBound(myArray)
      If UCase(myArray(y)) < UCase(myArray(x)) Then
        TempTxt1 = myArray(x)
        TempTxt2 = myArray(y)
        myArray(x) = TempTxt2
        myArray(y) = TempTxt1
      End If
     Next y
  Next x

  i = 0
  For Each Item In myArray
    result = result & myArray(i)
    i = i + 1
  Next Item

  MsgBox result

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will accept strInput (any string) and return strOuput as that string sorted alphabetically ascending.

```
strOutput = Left(strInput, 1)

For intCnt = 2 To Len(strInput)
    strChar = Mid(strInput, intCnt, 1)
    For intChk = 1 To Len(strOutput)
        If strChar < Mid(strOutput, intChk, 1) Then
            strOutput = Left(strOutput, intChk - 1) + strChar + Mid(strOutput, intChk)
            strChar = ""
            Exit For
        End If
    Next intChk
    strOutput = strOutput + strChar
Next intCnt
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself:

```
Function test_function(typestr As String)

    For i = 1 To Len(typestr) - 1
        For j = i + 1 To Len(typestr)
            If Mid(typestr, i, 1) > Mid(typestr, j, 1) Then
                temp = Mid(typestr, i, 1)
                typestr = Replace(typestr, Mid(typestr, i, 1), Mid(typestr, j, 1), 1, 1)
                typestr = Left(typestr, j - 1) & Replace(typestr, Mid(typestr, j, 1), temp, j, 1)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    test_function = typestr

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The minimal change I know of is to use `Mid()` on the *left-hand* side of an assignment (which works!):

```
Option Explicit

Public Function test_function(typeStr As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim temp As String

    For i = 1 To Len(typeStr) - 1
        For j = i + 1 To Len(typeStr)
            If Mid(typeStr, i, 1) > Mid(typeStr, j, 1) Then
                temp = Mid(typeStr, i, 1)
                Mid(typeStr, i, 1) = Mid(typeStr, j, 1)    ' <====
                Mid(typeStr, j, 1) = temp                  ' <====
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    test_function = typeStr
End Function
```

With the swap fixed, `test_function("aoiszb")` returns `abiosz`.

The only substantive changes I made were to the two lines marked `<====`.  Other than that, I added the code necessary to make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  I also added `Option Explicit` since it helps catch bugs and (in my personal opinion) should always be used.